# How to fill an empty space with numbers

Tags: c#

I need it to be like the example here:

```
01230
01231
01232
01233
```

What I have right now

```
01230
1
2
3
```

and my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Console.Write(i);
}

    
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: Maybe `Console.WriteLine()`?

Comment: Can't understand what you mean. 
What empty space are you talking about?

Comment: Do you mean you want to leftpad/prefix the logged numbers with `0123_`

Comment: I need that from the second line the numbers go down and fill the empty space where there are no numbers yet

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("0123{0}", i);`?

Comment: Can you please explain the pattern of how to numbers are filled acutually

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"0123{i}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
  {
      Console.Write(j);
  }
      Console.WriteLine(i);
      Console.WriteLine();
}
```